# Telegram does display my link preview

Tags: html, telegram

My problem is about [telegram link preview](https://telegram.org/blog/link-preview).

I have a vps server (Ubuntu) and I upload one image to HTML folder.

**No any domain is setup on my vps and I access to vps server with IP**

I can see my image by calling URL in browser like this:

http://176.9.164.177/111.jpg

I place this URL in telegram but telegram don't display **link preview** and my image don't show in my telegram post.

Comment: Simply assign a domain name to your IP and the image will be shown. There are a couple of free domain names. Google it.